# Return type for method chaining

Tags: coldfusion, chaining, method-chaining, coldfusion-11

What is the return type when using method chaining? `any` seems to be too generic.

```
<cffunction name="get" output="false" returntype="any">
   <cfargument name="BossID" type="string" required="false" default="All">
   ...
   <cfreturn this>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Just curious, but given that CF is relatively typeless anyway, does this really have any affect on chaining?

Comment: It doesn't seem to have any effect, but I want to make sure the right thing is listed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well think it through: what is it you're returning? You're returning the object itself. So... what sort of object is that? It's the *name of the component*.